# What would cause an automatic update of Pipfile.lock?

Tags: pipenv

Yesterday I encountered a problem in a GitHub Actions workflow that issues these commands:

```bash
pip install pipenv
pipenv install --dev
pipenv run dbt deps
```

`dbt` is a tool installed from pip package dbt-core. Here is **Pipfile**:

```ini
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
dbt-core = "==1.5.4"
dbt-snowflake = "~=1.5"

[dev-packages]
pytest = "==7.1.2"
pytest-env = "==0.6.2"
schemachange = "==3.5.3"
pre-commit = "*"
black = "*"
isort = "*"
cryptography= "==41.0.6"
mypy = "==1.3.0"

[requires]
python_version = "3.10"
```

The error in my GitHub Actions workflow run was:

> /bin/sh: 1: dbt: not found

Evidently `dbt` had not been installed when `pipenv install --dev` was executed. I found the root cause, `dbt` did not appear in **Pipfile.lock** so I issued `pipenv lock`, pushed the new **Pipfile.lock**, and my workflow then succeeded.

There is a mystery here though. The workflow had been working successfully for quite some time before yesterday's failure and there was no change evident to me that could have suddenly caused it to fail.

I compared the logs of the most recently succeeded run:

> Successfully installed certifi-2023.11.17 distlib-0.3.8 filelock-3.13.1 pipenv-2023.11.15 platformdirs-4.1.0 setuptools-69.0.3 virtualenv-20.25.0.
> Loading .env environment variables...
> Pipfile.lock (5e4bb6) out of date, updating to (a67c89)...
> Locking [packages] dependencies...
> Building requirements...
> Resolving dependencies...
> Success!
> Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
> Building requirements...
> Resolving dependencies...
> Success!
> Updated Pipfile.lock (65984eea698a6fd36e7dbe3756a5185f36aa6e464d0ed1e9a3aa506b06a67c89)!
> Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (a67c89)...
> Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (a67c89)...
> To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
> Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
> Loading .env environment variables...
> 12:05:49  Running with dbt=1.5.4.

with the logs of the failed run:

> Successfully installed certifi-2023.11.17 distlib-0.3.8 filelock-3.13.1 pipenv-2023.11.15 platformdirs-4.1.0 setuptools-69.0.3 virtualenv-20.25.0
> Loading .env environment variables...
> Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (1f3b12)...
> Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (1f3b12)...
> To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
> Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
> Loading .env environment variables...
> /bin/sh: 1: dbt: not found.
> Error: Process completed with exit code 127.

It is clear to see that on the successful run `pipenv` realised that **Pipfile.lock** was out of date (which, I assume, means that **Pipfile.lock** is not consistent with **Pipfile**) and hence updated it:

> Pipfile.lock (5e4bb6) out of date, updating to (a67c89)...

However it did not do that on the failed run.

My question is....why? More specifically:

- In what circumstances would `pipenv` automatically update the lock file?
- In what circumstances would `pipenv` *not* automatically update the lock file?